# $wpdb->get_results returns nothing on server, but works on local - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a table called ccc_campaigns in my database and I am retrieving the data with the following statement:

```
global $wpdb;

$campaign_list = $wpdb->get_results( 
                'SELECT * 
                 FROM ccc_campaigns 
                 ORDER BY id DESC');
```

This works as expected on my local and on one of my servers, the data is displayed doing:

```
foreach ($campaign_list as $campaign)
```

But in the server where this wordpress is supposed to be, the query comes back empty. I can't understand or find a reason why it is failing on that server.

Any ideas?

Thank you so much

Comment: Is Db Case sentive??

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question

Comment: Same name of table? because in my project the query was not working because the table was in capitals and in the query was written in lowercase

Comment: ah ok, yeah same exactly name, I used the same sql script to make it -.-

Comment: Uhm very strange, maybe you need to reset query with wp_reset_query

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the **database prefix** are the same.

**EDIT:** I guess you are building some kind of plugin, so just to make sure, db prefix is not causing any errors, use this function instead.

```
function getCampaignResults(){
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "campaigns";
    $active_rows = $wpdb->get_results(
        "SELECT * FROM {$table_name}"
    );

    foreach ($active_rows as $active_row){
        echo $active_row->the_title;
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case I am not using database prefix for my table

Comment: well you are using the prefix ccc_ for local, make sure the table name has the same prefix for live as well.

Comment: Its stupid to ask, but is there any data in the table :P

Comment: mmmm but ccc_campaigns is the name of the table, my other tables use the prefix wp_ for example wp_options, so I have in my database tables like wp_options and my table ccc_campaigns

Comment: Well do you have the same structure for the local db as well?